# CMake is not able to find LAPACK sgemm on macOS

Tags: macos, cmake, lapack, blas, accelerate-framework

I'm trying to compile [this code](https://github.com/ElmerCSC/elmerfem/tree/wip/mac), but when running `cmake ..` in the build folder I get the messages:

```
-- Looking for Fortran sgemm
-- Looking for Fortran sgemm - not found
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Success
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Looking for Fortran dgemm
-- Looking for Fortran dgemm - found
-- Found BLAS: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework  
-- Looking for Fortran cheev
-- Looking for Fortran cheev - found
-- A library with LAPACK API found.
```

showing that CMake was not able to find the `sgemm` LAPACK routine. This is strange because later, CMake says that it has found BLAS and LAPACK through Accelerate Framework.

My environment is:

- CMake 3.17.0
- macOS Catalina 10.15.4

and compilers are GNU GCC 9.3.0 installed via HomeBrew:

- `/usr/local/bin/gcc-9`
- `/usr/local/bin/gfortran`

I would appreciate it if you could help me know what is the problem and how I can solve it.

**P.S.** relevant discussion/code [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/19073), [here](https://github.com/elemental/Elemental/blob/master/cmake/external_projects/ElMath.cmake), and [here](https://www.ivofilot.nl/posts/view/33/How+to+compile+VASP+5.4.1+on+a+MacBook+running+OS+X+El+Capitan)